# R: how to pass functions as arguments to another function

Tags: r

Suppose I want to integrate some function that involves sums and products of a few other user defined functions. Lets take an extremely simple example, it gives the same error.

```
integrate(f = sin + cos, lower=0, upper=1)
```

This yields "Error in sin + cos : non-numeric argument to binary operator" which I think is saying it doesn't make sense to just add functions together without passing them some sort of argument. So I am a bit stuck here. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426730/how-can-i-find-the-sum-of-a-list-of-functions-in-r/7428012#7428012) poses what I think is a solution to a more complicated question, that can be applied here, but it seems long for such a simple task in this case. I'm actually kind of surprised that I am unable to find passing function arguments to functions in the help manual so I think I am not using the right terminology.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just write your own function:

```
> integrate(f = function(x) sin(x) + cos(x), lower=0, upper=1)
1.301169 with absolute error < 1.4e-14
```

In this example I've used an anonymous function, but that's not necessary. The key is to write a function that represents whatever function you want to integrate over. In this case, the function should take a vector input and add the sin and cos of each element.

Equivalently, we could have done:

```
foo <- function(x){
    sin(x) + cos(x)
}
integrate(f = foo, lower=0, upper=1)
```

Comment: That is to say, what you want to add together (mathematically) is the result of the function (`sin(x)` and `cos(x)`), not the functions themselves.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I recently struggled with it, so here is a simple example in case it helps others in the future. @joran's answer is still the best.

Define your first function: `f1 <- function(x){return(x*2)}`

Test it: `f1(8)` (expect 8*2=16); returns `[1] 16`

Define your second function: `f2 <-function(f, y){return(f+y)}`

Test it: `f2(f=f1(8), y=1)` (expect 8*2 = 16 +1 = 17); returns `[1] 17`